# Turning unallocated space into an NTFS partition

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, partitioning, gparted

I want to dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 7. Here's my GParted configuration:

[image]

I want to set all the unallocated space to use the NTFS system so I can store my media files.

```
dev/sda1 is MBR
dev/sda2 is primary partition for win7 application and installaion
dev/sda3 is primary partition for ubuntu11 application and installation
dev/sda4 is logical partition for /home and swap in ubuntu.
```

In GParted, I can't make a new partition. I got an error that said I can't have four primary partitions.

How can I do this? Or is there a problem with partitioning the disk like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extend /dev/sda4 to the end of the disk. You can only have up to 4 'primary partitions' on this disk. Once you expand it, you can create an NTFS partition (a Logical partition) at the end inside of /dev/sda4

Comment: @how can i extend the /dev/sda4? I can't extend it on gparted :p

Comment: @KitHo http://gparted.sourceforge.net/larry/resize/resizing.htm half-way down explains it

Comment: I don't know if it is locked (see the screen capture), The Resize/Move option is disabled when I point to my extended drive

Answer (score 1):

You have to use GParted on an Ubuntu boot disk, and DO NOT MOUNT any of the logical partitions OR the extended partitions. Now, you can resize the extended partition. Follow the directions in the other answer(create another NTFS partiton inside the logical partition.