# Create another partition when all primary partitions are in use

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Turning unallocated space into an NTFS partition](https://superuser.com/questions/370729/turning-unallocated-space-into-an-ntfs-partition)
>   [Partitioning Disk: Maximum Partitions Reached](https://superuser.com/questions/374013/partitioning-disk-maximum-partitions-reached)

My hard disc contains unallocated space and I want to format this space but I already use the maximum number of primary partitions.

I use Win7 (partitions: System Reserved,C,D) and Ubuntu(976MB swap and 55.88GB)

I searched on the Internet and I found that I can convert my disk to dynamic disc and then create the new partition, but I am not sure how to do this.

How can I use this unallocated space (from windows) without losing any data?

Comment: If you don't want to lose any data make a backup before you touch anything.

Comment: I edited your question, feel free to revert the changes if you don't like them or edit it again yourself. I think this question has been asked before on superuser but I cannot find it.

Comment: If you want Linux to keep working, then do not convert to a dynamic disc.

Comment: See the two posts I linked to

Comment: @Luke if i extend the last partition to the end of the disk and create NTFS partition ,is this NTFS partition will be available from windows?

Comment: @HeshamAbouelsoaod Read the other posts; but yes, as long as Windows sees a partition is NTFS or FAT (for hard drives), it will assign a drive letter and be accessible to you

Comment: @Luke i read the other posts thank you,but i have the same problem happened with "kit Ho" ,the problem is that the Resize/move option in Gparted is disabled for my extend partition!

Comment: @heshamabouelsoaod Not at a PC right now, but I will take a second look for you when I am